# List dates occurring at intervals of n days within date range

Tags: calendar

I would like to supply a date range and a numbe r(n) and list all the dates occurring at intervals of n days in that range.

For example, if the starting date is 22 April 2017 and the end date is 19 December 2017, I want to print the dates in steps of 11 days from 22 April 2017. The first date would be 3 May 2017, the next one 14 May 2017 and so on. In this example n=11.

Comment: What do you mean by "list the dates"? What information (day of month, day of week, year, etc.?) do you want displayed, and how do you want it displayed? Please **[edit]** this with at least one example of a possible *input* you might provide and the desired *output* for that input, and also clarify what sort of task you are trying to accomplish. Do you just want to have a terminal command you can run? Do you want to write a shell script? Or are you looking for a graphical app that does this? Someone *might* guess what you mean and answer... but the question isn't clear.

Comment: Is there a specific programming language you want to accomplish this with? What have you tried so far? Please review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
start="22 April 2017"
end=$(date +%s -d "19 December 2017")
i=0
while (($(date +%s -d "$start + $i days") < end))
do
    date +%F -d "$start + $i days"
    ((i+=11))
done
```

GNU `date`  allows expressions like `<date> + <n> days`. `+%s` is the Unix timestamp and `+F` the date in `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Output:

```
2017-04-22
2017-05-03
2017-05-14
2017-05-25
2017-06-05
2017-06-16
2017-06-27
2017-07-08
2017-07-19
2017-07-30
2017-08-10
2017-08-21
2017-09-01
2017-09-12
2017-09-23
2017-10-04
2017-10-15
2017-10-26
2017-11-06
2017-11-17
2017-11-28
2017-12-09
```